# How do I choose between two appenders based on a condition and define in log4j.properties?

Tags: java, log4j

How do I choose between two appenders based on a condition and define in log4j.properties?  My requirement is , if a condition is satisfied use appender A, else use appender B

**log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern= [%t] [%10v] [%p] [%c]
log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender**

*OR*

**log4j.appender.B.layout.ConversionPattern= [%10v] [%p] [%c]
log4j.appender.B=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender**